# momentjs returns error "lastseen.diff is not a function"

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

I am comparing date with the help of Momentjs in Angular.

```
     curdate = moment();
       curdate = curdate.format('DD-MM-YYYY');
lastseen = moment(data.last_seen); //this data is coming from database (DD-MM-YYYY)

lastseen = lastseen.isValid();
duration = lastseen.diff(curdate, 'days') ;
alert(lastseen); // it is returning false.

alert(duration);
```

In Firebug I am getting below error.

> Error: lastseen.diff is not a function
>
> Object { _i: "09-02-2017", _f: undefined, _l: undefined, _isUTC: false, _d: Invalid Date }

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are assigning the boolean value here "lastseen = lastseen.isValid();" so change the variable name "flag = lastseen.isValid();"

Comment: that was for testing. i have commented that code. while testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can skip this line `lastseen = lastseen.isValid();` because when you do this.. last seen become a boolean value i.e true or false. this value does not  have a function `diff.`

```js
curdate = moment();
// skip this like.. use moment object
      // curdate = curdate.format('DD-MM-YYYY');
lastseen = moment("24-02-2017",'DD-MM-YYYY'); //this data is coming from database (DD-MM-YYYY)
//skip this also
//lastseen = lastseen.isValid();
duration = lastseen.diff(curdate, 'days') ;
alert(lastseen); // it is returning false.

alert(duration);
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: i tried that but it is not working. I am getting Error: lastseen.diff is not a function

Comment: Object { _i: "09-02-2017", _f: undefined, _l: undefined, _isUTC: false, _d: Invalid Date }

Comment: skip this also 'curdate = curdate.format('DD-MM-YYYY');' . you have compare objects.. 
and date have to parse first lastseen = moment("24-02-2017",'DD-MM-YYYY');

Answer (score 1):

Replace this

```
lastseen = moment(data.last_seen);
```

with

```
lastseen  = moment(data.last_seen, "MM-DD-YYYY");
```

and DO NOT replace lastseen with a boolean

```
lastseen = lastseen.isValid();
```

Answer (score 1):

For more details on [**moment.js Difference**](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {

 var curdate = moment();
  var lastseen = moment('12-02-2017','DD-MM-YYYY'); //this data is coming from database (DD-MM-YYYY)

  var flag = lastseen.isValid();
  var duration = curdate.diff(lastseen, 'days');
  alert(flag); // it is returning false.

  //Adding plus to include start date, If you want to include
  alert(duration+1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  {{resultados}}
</div>
```